# Ruby comparing if these 2 values DO NOT exist

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, comparison, enumeration

**What I'm trying to do**
In my Model, I want to select only the items that are NOT equal to (a or b) to. So I did this which works.

`# This works`
`select { | item | item.attribute != a}.select {| item | item.attribute != b}`

**Question**
This chaining works, but is there a another way of writing this ?
What happens if I wanted to also check c and d ? Would I add some array somewhere ?
I wouldn't keep chaining would I ?

**Follow Up Question**
The `select` line will work in my model, but when I try to put the `reject` line in my model I get a `undefined method reject for #<Class>`

`class Model < ActiveRecord::Base`

`def self.foo`
    `arr = [a,b]`
    `reject { | item | arr.include?(item.attribute)}`
`end`

`end`

I'm guessing ActiveRecord does not understand `reject` ? Does ActiveRecord have a method that is similar to SQL `NOT LIKE` ?

Comment: I'm not so familiar with ActiveRecord, so hopefully someone can help you more with that more.

Comment: You have to call `reject` on some array of ActiveRecord objects. From what do you intend to reject? For example in phoffers code, heis rejecting from `items`. You have to define this somewhere and call `reject` on it.

Answer (score 2):

We'll say that `items` is your array of items that you are using `#select` on.

```
arr = [a, b] # or [a, b, c, d]
items.reject { |item| arr.include?(item.attribute) }
```

This reverses your select into reject, but rejects the items that ARE equal to (a or b).

Comment: This works! The only question I have is for some reason I cannot get this to work in my Model.

Comment: What is the full code you have in your model? Note, this does not change `items`, you would have to do either `new_items = items.reject...` or do `items.reject!`. `#reject!` modifies the original array.

Comment: My model is an ActiveRecord model.

Comment: Write `all.reject` to convert it into an array first. However you might reconsider writing your code depending on how many models you will have in your DB. This should better be an SQL query.

Comment: To convert it into array is not working right. I think your right I probably need to create some SQL query for this. I'll do some research.